# Can only access NodePort service through the worker node the app is running on

Tags: kubernetes, service-node-port-range

I am running an on-premise, vmware cluster with HA master nodes and two worker nodes. Both worker nodes are "ready", and the cluster has a NodePort service for running a web server. I am able to access the web page through the worker node directly, but cannot access it through the other worker node in the cluster. I have also added the "iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT" to fix the issue that has worked in the past, but it seems to no longer be working. Does anyone have any ideas that could fix this issue?

Comment: How are you running your kubernetes cluster (kubeadm? kubespray? k8sthehardway?) and what is the operating system you are running on?

Comment: Deployed with kubeadm, k8s version 1.14.2. Centos 7 OS.

Comment: Looking at the iptables rules, it looks as if this would not be the issue since I have used the iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT in the past to work around. Wondering if there is something with calico networking that is causing the issue rather than the OS routing rules?

Comment: try running `sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1`

Comment: I am using ansible to set pre-requisites, and I have that set in the playbook. I ran it manually, but it did not work, still failing to access the service. It is not blocked by a firewall, and running netstat -tulnp shows the port is listening for the services running in the cluster. @HelloWorld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have worked when reapplying the "iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT" and restarting both docker and kubelet.